# Render only HTML using jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I am using Jinja2 to render a html page, which in turn have a Javascript code that generates a div. I need the html resulting with the executed JavaScript code, not the tag  like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>create_a_div()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The desired output is:

```
<html>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any argument I could use in the function render to do this?

I would let that JavaScript code to be executed on Client side,
but I am not allowed to save it for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand what you are asking for, I'm afraid the answer is **no**, you cannot execute the JavaScript code in render function.

What you could do, is pass the html as a **variable** into the **template** with the **safe** filter.

**Template:**

```
<html>
<body>
  {{ custom_html|safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

**And when rendering, use the following Python code:**

```
template.render(custom_html="<div>your html code</div>")
```

This would give you the desired output that you are looking for.

You can read more about JINJA2 templates and variables [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/)